# fetch data from URL in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, string, visual-studio-2010, url

i am new to asp.net,

ı want to get data from url on asp.net. & need data to be  in store into string.

if suppose this is my URL thn i want to fetch this URL Data in string,

```
http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=bahrain&city=manama&state=02&zipcode=&latitude=26.2361&longitude=50.5831&timezone=3.00&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=4&fajrTwilight1=&fajrTwilight2=&ishaTwilight=0&ishaInterval=0&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=0&simpleFormat=xml
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
string url = "http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayer_service.php?country=bahrain&city=manama&state=02&zipcode=&latitude=26.2361&longitude=50.5831&timezone=3.00&HanfiShafi=1&pmethod=4&fajrTwilight1=&fajrTwilight2=&ishaTwilight=0&ishaInterval=0&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=0&simpleFormat=xml";
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string data = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: i want to store this data into my table, how should i, do this ?

Comment: @krunal It depends on a lot of things. What database are you using? what data access technology?

Comment: i am not using any db, i just want to store this data in my HTML TABLE.. how should i, do this ?

Comment: @krunal you'll need to provide more info on how you want the table formated. is the table already on the page? pls edit your question to enable me answer accurately or create a new question and paste the link here.

Comment: i want to fetch data from this url "http://ipad.idealake.com/default.aspx?id=G" and i want to display this data in my HTML Table..  i tried this ("http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/24/fill-asp.net-table-with-data-from-datatable.aspx") code but it shows me error in form1.

Comment: for eg: my 1st row  is " DRREDDY  1712.55  1693.05  1.15 "  2nd row: MARUTI  1315.70  1309.55  0.47 ... and so on.

Comment: @krunal create a new question, post your code and explain what issues you are having and then come back here to post the stackoverflow link to your question. i'll be able to help if u do that. we can't solve it via comments

Answer (score 2):

[`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is useful for this kind of thing (scartag's answer demonstrates the simplicity of this), but for more advanced options you should look at the underlying [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class:

```
// Create a request for the URL.        
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");

// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (response.StatusDescription);

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();

// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);

// Cleanup the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```